# I am validating a json file with a json schema using java, how to log the elements of my json mismatching with the jsonschema?

Tags: json-schema-validator

How to log the mismatch elements while validating a json file against a json-schema?

I used json-schema-validator, but it just showing whether the json matches with the schema or not. 
It is not listing the mismatch element